# Google BigQuery CASE function

Tags: sql, case, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query like what's answered here,
[SQL Selecting multiple sums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821751/sql-selecting-multiple-sums)

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN order_date >= '01/01/09' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS items_sold_since_date,
    SUM(quantity) AS items_sold_total,
    product_ID
FROM    Sales
GROUP BY product_ID
```

But if I try that, I get the error message

```
"message": "Unrecognized function CASE".
```

If I try a much more simple (from an sql tutorial),

```
SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN 'one' WHEN 2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'more' END;
```

I then get

```
"message": "searched case expression not supported at: 1.8 - 1.65".
```

I'm going to take a wild stab in the dark and assume that the SQL CASE function is overall just not supported on BigQuery, but really hope that I'm wrong because it makes a huge bit of difference based on the report queries I want to run.

Comment: Seems that indeed it not supports CASE clause https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference

Comment: Yeah, I did check there alright, but the fact that they give version numbers led me to thinking that there was potentially an area where I could swap my version to a newer one that supports it.  Very frustrating, it'd make the queries I need much easier.

Comment: CASE is supported now, see below

Comment: CASE is supported BUT just as 'searched case' and not 'simple case' expression (as of 24th Feb 2016). Just in case somebody stumbles upon and is wondering, took me too long to figure it out

Answer (score 39, accepted):

2013 update: BigQuery supports CASE:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN x=1 THEN 'one' WHEN x=2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'more' END 
FROM (SELECT 1 AS x) 

'one'
```

Comment: Thanks for updating with the much better answer for anyone looking for that now.  I'm not working with BigQuery any more, but I may be again in the future and the more things like above that it's adding makes it all the more appealing.

Comment: What's the standard SQL version?

Comment: Found it. It's also CASE https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conditional-expressions

Answer (score 6):

The way to do this in BigQuery is to use the if(test,then,else) function.
For example:
`SELECT sum(if (revision_id > 10, num_characters, 0)) FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]`
or similar to your second query:

`SELECT if (revision_id == 1, 'one', (if (revision_id == 2, 'two', 'more'))) FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] limit 100`

Comment: 2013 update: BigQuery supports case: SELECT CASE WHEN x=1 THEN 'one' WHEN x=2 THEN 'two' ELSE 'more' END
FROM (SELECT 1 AS x)