# Trouble building an effective BigQuery CASE statement

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am having difficultly building an effective BigQuery case statement for a fairly complex reporting query. The data set that I am using has been populated by Google Analytics. For this query, there are many cases, but this is one of the cases that I am looking at:

```
CASE when previous page="^/XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/traveler\.aspx" and landing page="^/XXX/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Traveler info 2.0" 
when previous page="^/web/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/traveler\.aspx" and landing page="^/web/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Traveler info 1.0"  when previous
```

Note here that the XXX and the web are different cases. The wrinkle in this is that the one needs to determine whether the page path is a landing page or not, in order to deal with the cases. I currently have a separate question out in that area. For this specific issues, I have looked at many resources, including the following resource on SO, [which introduces the BigQuery case function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647201/google-bigquery-case-function) To support the question, here is the full case statement that will be constructed.

```
Case when page = "^/XXX/[^/]+/default\.aspx" and landing page="^/XXX/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Homepage 2.0" 
when page ="^/web/[^/]+/default\.aspx" and landing page = "^/web/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Homepage 1.0" 
when page="^XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking?flight/(searchresult1|search(rt|ow|md))\.aspx" and landing page="^/XXX/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Rev inbound search 2.0" 
when page="^web/[^/]+/apps/booking?flight/(searchresult1|search(rt|ow|md))\.aspx" and landing page="^/web/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Rev inbound search 1.0" 
when page="^/XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/searchResult2\.aspx" and previous page ="^XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking?flight/(searchresult1|search(rt|ow|md))\.aspx" and landing page="^/XXX/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Rev outbound search 2.0" 
when page="^/web/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/searchResult2\.aspx" and previous page="^web/[^/]+/apps/booking?flight/(searchresult1|search(rt|ow|md))\.aspx" landing page="^/web/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Rev outbound search 1.0" 
when page="^/XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/reviewRevenue\.aspx" and previous page="^/XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/searchResult2\.aspx" and landing page="^/XXX/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Rev review itinerary 2.0" 
when page="^/web/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/reviewRevenue\.aspx" and previous page="^/web/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/searchResult2\.aspx" and landing page="^/web/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Rev review itinerary 1.0"  
when page="^/XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/traveler\.aspx" and previous page="^/XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/reviewRevenue\.aspx" and landing page="^/XXX/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Rev traveler info 2.0" 
when page="^/web/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/traveler\.aspx" and previous page="^/web/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/reviewRevenue\.aspx" and landing page="^/web/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Rev traveler info 1.0"  
when page="^/XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/seatSelector\.aspx" and previous page="^/XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/traveler\.aspx" and landing page="^/XXX/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Rev seat selector 2.0" 
when page="^/web/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/seatSelector\.aspx" and previous page="^/web/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/traveler\.aspx" and landing page="^/web/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Rev seat selector 1.0" 
when page="^/XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/billingRevenue\.aspx" and previous page="^/XXX/[^/]+/apps/booking/flight/seatSelector\.aspx" and landing page="^/XXX/[^/]+/default\.aspx" then "Rev payment info 2.0"
```

My first instinct here was to create a new column (potentially), that looks at the path the user took to determine which case the unique visit should be part of. This may not be the best direction and is something that I was exploring. The other, is to use the case function directly. Any initial support or insight one can shed on the best way to approach this part of the query would be exceptional.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how often do you run the query.
If it is a Ad Hoc analysis i wouldn't bother with creating new fields.
If you intend to run it very often, I would create an additional field while populating the BQ table, and hold a short string with the relevant info there.

The concern is not about efficiency of the query (let the BQ guys worry about this), but about query costs. Querying very often a field with very long strings (such as the URL) is costly. If you can hold a significantly shorter pre-calculated string, you can save some money.

Another option i suggest for you to explore is parsing your strings using the Regx_Extract function. it might be more readable, and a bit shorter.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I am continuing to make progress now. I have the case statement functioning but am working to have the statement results copied to all entries corresponding to a column value (the unique visit ID that I created). Once I can do that I should be in a good position. And, great points on the cost. For now, the report piece is Ad Hoc. That said, it will definitely be going to a more automated approach soon.

Comment: I'd second @N.N's suggestion to use regexp_extract. You can use a subquery that pulls interesting pieces out of the path, and gives them convenient names that can be used in the outer query. The outer query would then be much more readable, easier to modify, and less likely to have bugs.

Comment: Here is where I am stuck. What is the best way to do regexp_extract and apply the results to all of the values corresponding to a unique visits. For context, I used CONCAT(fullVisitorId, STRING(visitId)) AS unique_visit_id to create a unique visit ID. If one of the URL's matches what I am looking for within the visit, what is the most efficient way to cast this result into a new column that has the same values for all the unique visit ID's. Would WITHIN work well? I will keep at it and report results back as I make progress.

Comment: I have now appended this question based on progress with the queries and added a new specific question relating to the task of the CASES (with specific hypothetical screen shots). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747744/using-a-case-statement-to-change-the-value-of-a-new-bigquery-column-based-findin