# Using a CASE statement to change the value of a new BigQuery column based finding one specific entry inside a PARTITION

Tags: google-bigquery

I trying to write some case statements which might change the value of all entries in the call if a particular condition is satisfied INSIDE the partition. Here is the specific context. Imagine that I have a particular data set that was created using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT date, CONCAT(fullVisitorId, STRING(visitId)) AS unique_visit_id, visitId, visitNumber, fullVisitorId, totals.pageviews, totals.bounces, 
LAG(hits.page.pagePath,1) OVER(PARTITION BY unique_visit_id ORDER BY hits.time ASC) as lagged, hits.page.pagePath, hits.page.pageTitle, device.deviceCategory, device.browser, device.browserVersion, hits.customVariables.index,
hits.customVariables.customVarName, hits.customVariables.customVarValue, hits.time
FROM (FLATTEN([XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_20140711], hits.time))
WHERE hits.customVariables.index = 4
LIMIT 1000;
```

The resulting data sets looks similar to the following (shown in excel):

[image: Snapshot showing the data frame]

Note that the unique_visit_id has the same number in it for each unique visit. What I would like to do in many instances is run through the hits_page_pagePath. I would like to construct a CASE statement such that, when the lagged URL (found using REGEX_MATCH()) equals a particular value, and the value of the hits_page_pagePath equals a certain value when hits_time = 0, then create a new column using case that labels the entire partition a certain value. For example, let's say that I found an error in the hits_page_pagePath and the lagged value was a certain value. In this case, I would then make the entire partition labelled "Booking error". If the lagged value was a different one before the error, I would make the partition be a different label, such as "Payment error". The table would then look like the one below:

[image]

This would repeat for all the unique_visit_id partitions. I would then be able to group together counts of total bounces, hits, events, etc., for each partition. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible that this could be done with a smart usage of analytics functions, but my SQL-fu isn't up to it. That said, it sounds like what you want is achievable with a simple JOIN statement. Let's say your current query is called Q (you could even save this as a view to make it easier).

Run

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.has_some_property
FROM Q AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT unique_visit_id, 1 as has_some_property
  FROM Q 
  WHERE (REGEXP_MATCH(lagged, ...) 
      AND REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.pagePath))
  GROUP BY unique_visit_id
  ) AS t2
ON t1.unique_visit_id == t2.unique_visit_id
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I had put down some notes on the join but was looking to try and find an intuitive way to do it using some of the analytics functions! Will have to channel my inner SQL-fu tonight & will share the results once I have something!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for avoiding joins, you can use an aggregated function with Over.
something like:

```
Max(If((Your Condition here),Your value here, Null)) Over( Partition By Your_Partition)
```

the window functions used to had some performance issues that should have been improved recently. 
My experience with BQ drives me to prefer Jordan's Join suggestion. But hey, its a fun riddle...

Comment: Thanks! I am going to work on both and see what turns out! The wrinkle is that I likely will need to embed this inside a CASE function (which is why I was looking at the aggregate function). That said, am open to suggestions!