# How to convert decode function in oracle to standard big query

Tags: sql, oracle

Can some one help me in converting the following oracle code to standard big query

```
SELECT
  Table1.BIC_ZC2ISBN10,
  sum ( decode(Table1.BIC_ZC2DCINDC,'H', (decode(Table1.BIC_ZC2MOVTYP,
       'Z03',Table1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2,
       'Z35',Table1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2,
       'Z64',Table1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2,
       'Z77',Table1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2,
        0)),0)   -  decode(Table1.BIC_ZC2DCINDC,'S', 
        (decode(BOADMIN.BIC_GM_AP2OINVS300_BO_VW.BIC_ZC2MOVTYP,
        'Z04',Table1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2,
        'Z36',Table1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2,
        'Z65',Table1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2,
         'Z78',Table1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2,
         0)),0) )
FROM
  Table1
GROUP BY
  Table1.BIC_ZC2ISBN10
```

I am new to big query and i have no idea on 'decode' function.

Thanks

Comment: see on docs what decode means: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions057.htm#SQLRF00631

Comment: Your query has two tables in the `SELECT` but only one in the `FROM`.  It won't run on any database (unless what looks like a table reference is really a nested table/struct reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @heregoes suggested that `case when` is available with big query, you can use the following query.

```
SELECT
    TABLE1.BIC_ZC2ISBN10,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN TABLE1.BIC_ZC2DCINDC = 'H' THEN CASE
            WHEN TABLE1.BIC_ZC2MOVTYP IN(
                'Z03', 'Z35', 'Z64', 'Z77'
            ) THEN TABLE1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2
            ELSE 0
        END
        ELSE 0
    END - CASE
        WHEN TABLE1.BIC_ZC2DCINDC = 'S'  THEN CASE
            WHEN BOADMIN.BIC_GM_AP2OINVS300_BO_VW.BIC_ZC2MOVTYP IN (
                'Z04',
                'Z36',
                'Z65',
                'Z78'
            ) THEN TABLE1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2
            ELSE 0
        END
        ELSE 0
    END
)
FROM TABLE1 
GROUP BY TABLE1.BIC_ZC2ISBN10;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

The CASE statement can be used instead of the DECODE

```
CASE expr WHEN value THEN result [WHEN ...] [ELSE else_result] END
```

Comment: Will it convert it to big query?

Comment: The CASE statement is available in bigquery... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647201/google-bigquery-case-function

Comment: Nice, it was not known to me.. thanks. Learned it. Upvoted the answer...Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  However, you do not need nested `CASE` expressions.  In fact, you do not even need *multiple* `CASE` expressions.  One suffices:

```
SELECT t1.BIC_ZC2ISBN10,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.BIC_ZC2DCINDC = 'H' AND
                     t1.BIC_ZC2MOVTYP IN ('Z03', 'Z35', 'Z64', 'Z77')
                THEN t1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2
                WHEN t1.BIC_ZC2DCINDC = 'S' AND 
                     bg.BIC_ZC2MOVTYP IN ('Z04', 'Z36', 'Z65', 'Z78')
                THEN - t1.BIC_ZK2CLABS2
                ELSE 0
           END)
. . .
```

Note that `BOADMIN.BIC_GM_AP2OINVS300_BO_VW` is not defined in your `FROM` clause.  I defined a table alias `bg` for it and `t1` for the first table.